# How to get all dates between given start and end date using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to get the dates between the given date and end date.

for example: if i get the values of start date `2013-02-20` and end date `2013-03-20` in Javascript, I need to check the in between values like `2013-02-20`, `2013-02-21`, `2013-02-22` with the another set of days 
..how can i get the in between values..?

Answer (score 1):

What the need to get using any function you can create your own

YOu have start date now loop it to  addDays(1) and store where ever you want to store say
in array and stop the loop at end date 
now check for the dates you want to check from array.

as simple as it could be. 
algo can be

```
you can use the following 
var someDate = new Date(); // or say your start date
var Datesbetween = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 1;
in  loop 
Check for EndDate
Datesbetween.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); // now store it where you want
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var noOfDays = dateDiff(dateEarlier,dateLater);
var myDates = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<noOfDays; i++)
{
   myDates[i] = dateEarlier.getDate() + (i + 1);
}
```

your function to get the date differences....

```
function dateDiff(dateEarlier, dateLater) {
    var one_day = 1000*60*60*24
    return (Math.round((dateLater.getTime()-dateEarlier.getTime())/one_day)  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like only to check if one date between two another dates, you can check difference between them, e.g.:

```
var dateEarlier, dateLater, dateCheck = new Date();
if ((dateCheck - dateEarlier > 0) && (dateLater - dateCheck > 0)) {
    /// do the stuff
}
```